# Adding a spacing between images in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

How does one add a gap/space between multiple images that are added to the UIScrollView?

one example would be photos app, which has black spacing between images when paging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just basic mathematics..

You add UIImageView as subviews, and compute the space you want knowing the size of your subviews and the contentSize of the scrollView.

EDIT :

This basically build a gallery

```
-(void)photosGallery
{
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin.x = 0.0f, .origin.y = 0.0f, .size.width = 320.0f, .size.height = 416.0f}];
    scrollView.contentSize = (CGSize){.width = view.frame.size.width, .height = 372.0f};
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    /// Build gallery
    CGSize thumbSize = (CGSize){.width = 75.0f, .height = 75.0f};
    const CGFloat xSpace = (scrollView.frame.size.width - (thumbSize.width * kPictsPerRow)) / (kPictsPerRow + 1); // kPictsPerRow = Number of pictures in a row
    const CGFloat xInc = thumbSize.width + xSpace;
    const CGFloat yInc = thumbSize.height + 15.0f;
    CGFloat x = xSpace, y = 10.0f;
    for (NSUInteger i = kMaxPictures; i--;)
    {
        UIImageView* pv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin.x = x, .origin.y = y, .size = thumbSize}];
        [scrollView addSubview:pv];
        [pv release];
        x += xInc;
        const NSUInteger eor = i % kPictsPerRow;

        if (!eor)
            y += yInc, x = xSpace;
    }
    [scrollView release];
}
```

Comment: I know, but how is the gap entered/added to the scrollview? IF the subview for each image is added to the scrollview, where is this math applied to the scrollView? how is it added?

Comment: @Benj: I setup my scrollview ok, one issue I have when adding all the images is the efficiency. It takes a while to load all the images into the view. Is there a optimal way of doing this?

Comment: It varies, it could be a lot.It is a bunch of ALAssets from the users phone. I basically recreated the photos app functionality, but am having a few efficiency issues.

Comment: I guess loading only the visible images, and loading them while scrolling could be better if you have a lot of images.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. How would one set the images in the scrollview to autorotate?

Comment: I never tries to do this but, you can try to use a UITableView.
This way the swapping will be handled by the tableView itself, you just have to write some custom cell like this : http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

Comment: Ok, but I think we have a misunderstanding. I already have the UITableView with custom cells, which displays the images as thumbnail in an album like in the photos app and that is fine. But I am now trying to get the UIScrollView to work nicely. The view which is displayed when an image is touched. The full screen imageview, which the user can scroll horizontally and view their images. This loading of images is slow and this is what my above issues relate too. ;)

Comment: Hey, check out my response below. I think it's a bit easier as it has less math calculations in it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 21):

I assume you know how to add images to UIScrollView with paging enabled. I also assume you want to see fullscreen photos, but when scrolling, you want to have gap between them. If yes, here's one of possible solutions ...

- define gap as 20px
- UIScrollView is fullscreen view, 320x480 for iPhone
- set UIScrollView frame to CGRectMake( 0, 0, 340, 480 ); // 340 = 320 + 20 (gap, these 20px are offscreen)
- set first image frame to CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 480 );
- second image frame to CGRectMake( 340, 0, 320, 480 );
- ... I-th image CGRectMake( 340 * I, 0, 320, 480 ) // I is index - 0..N-1
- set UIScrollView content size to CGSizeMake( 340 * N, 480 ) // N = number of images

... this is pretty fast solution if you do not want zooming, just fullscreen, paged, scrolling with gaps.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but for me the gap isn't sliding out of view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Just need to set the frames for the UIImageVIew's with some space between them. For example if scroll_view is a UIScrollView you could do

```
scroll_view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000,100);
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image.png"]];
    CGRect frame = CGRectInset(CGRectMake(i * 100,0.0,100.0,100.0), 5.0, 4.0);
    imv.frame = frame;
    [scroll_view addSubview:imv];
}
```

This is a crude example, but shows the point. By insetting the CGRect (CGRectInset), you get some spaces between images in the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in a similar app, and my solutions is documented in this answer (note that the question was not related to scroll views, but the concept involved is similar): [PDF in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732052/pdf-in-uiwebview/3732570#3732570)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this code:

```
#define FRAME_WIDTH 330
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FRAME_WIDTH, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    self.scrollView.bounces = YES;
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    UIImageView *leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
    leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height);

    UIImageView* centerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];
    centerView.frame = CGRectMake(FRAME_WIDTH, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height);

    UIImageView *rightView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"]];
    rightView.frame = CGRectMake(FRAME_WIDTH * 2, 0,320,self.view.bounds.size.height);

    [self.scrollView addSubview:leftView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:centerView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:rightView];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(FRAME_WIDTH * 3, 0)];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(FRAME_WIDTH, 0)];

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}
```

Looks like the iOS Photos app. This example creates 3 ImageViews.

Attached a Test project so you can try it yourself: [Project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13505993/Test.zip)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid messing with UIScrollView's frame, you could subclass UIScrollView and override layoutSubviews to apply an offset to each page.

The idea is based on the following observations:

1. When zoomScale !=1, the offset is zero when it is at the left / right edge
2. When zoomScale ==1, the offset is zero when it is at the visible rect centre

Then the following code is derived:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Find a reference point to calculate the offset:
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    CGFloat pageGap = 8.f;
    CGSize pageSize = bounds.size;
    CGFloat pageWidth = pageSize.width;
    CGFloat halfPageWidth = pageWidth / 2.f;
    CGFloat scale = self.zoomScale;
    CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x / scale, bounds.origin.y / scale, bounds.size.width / scale, bounds.size.height / scale);
    CGFloat totalWidth = [self contentSize].width / scale;
    CGFloat scrollWidth = totalWidth - visibleRect.size.width;
    CGFloat scrollX = CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect) - visibleRect.size.width / 2.f;
    CGFloat scrollPercentage = scrollX / scrollWidth;
    CGFloat referencePoint = (totalWidth - pageWidth) * scrollPercentage + halfPageWidth;

    // (use your own way to get all visible pages, each page is assumed to be inside a common container)
    NSArray * visiblePages = [self visiblePages];

    // Layout each visible page:
    for (UIView * view in visiblePages)
    {
        NSInteger pageIndex = [self pageIndexForView:view]; // (use your own way to get the page index)

        // make a gap between pages
        CGFloat actualPageCenter = pageWidth * pageIndex + halfPageWidth;
        CGFloat distanceFromRefPoint = actualPageCenter - referencePoint;
        CGFloat numOfPageFromRefPoint = distanceFromRefPoint / pageWidth;
        CGFloat offset = numOfPageFromRefPoint * pageGap;
        CGFloat pageLeft = actualPageCenter - halfPageWidth + offset;

        view.frame = CGRectMake(pageLeft, 0.f, pageSize.width, pageSize.height);
    }
}
```